# MatLab - algorithm for finding inverse of matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix-inverse

I am trying to write an algorithm in MatLab which takes as its input a lower triangular matrix.  The output should be the inverse of this matrix (which also should be in lower triangular form).  I have almost managed to solve this, but one part of my algorithm still leaves me scratching my head.  So far I have:

```
function AI = inverse(A)
n = length(A);
I = eye(n);
AI = zeros(n);
for k = 1:n
    AI(k,k) = (I(k,k) - A(k,1:(k-1))*AI(1:(k-1),k))/A(k,k);
    for i = k+1:n
        AI(i,k) = (I(i,k) - (??????????????))/A(i,i);
    end
end
```

I have marked with question marks the part I am unsure of.  I have tried to find a pattern for this part of the code by writing out the procedure on paper, but I just can't seem to find a proper way to solve this part.

If anyone can help me out, I would be very grateful!

Comment: Why can't you just use inv(A)?

Comment: @diophantine:  Because I am trying to learn the nuts and bolts of algorithms :).  And the problem I posted above is an exercise given in my textbook.  Of course, I know that I could just use inv(A), but learning how to construct algorithms from scratch is the goal of the course I am currently taking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my code to get the inverse of a lower triangular matrix by using row transformation:

```
function AI = inverse(A)
    len = length(A);
    I  = eye(len);
    M  = [A I];
    for row = 1:len
        M(row,:) = M(row,:)/M(row,row);
        for idx = 1:row-1
            M(row,:) = M(row,:) - M(idx,:)*M(row,idx);
        end
    end
    AI = M(:,len+1:end);
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can see how it's done on [Octave's source](http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/file/535bb601e7db/libinterp/corefcn/inv.cc). This seems to be implemented in different places depending on the class of the matrix. For Float type Diagonal Matrix it's on `liboctave/array/fDiagMatrix.cc`, for Complex Diagonal matrix it's on `liboctave/array/CDiagMatrix.cc`, etc...

One of the advantages of free (as in freedom) software is that you are free to study how things are implemented ;)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the input!  I was actually able to find a very nice and easy way to solve this problem today, given that the input is a lower triangular matrix:

```
function AI = inverse(A)
n = length(A);
I = eye(n);
AI = zeros(n);
for k = 1:n
    for i = 1:n
        AI(k,i) = (I(k,i) - A(k,1:(k-1))*AI(1:(k-1),i))/A(k,k);
    end
end
```